# How to multiply a sparse matrix by a sparse matrix element-wise in pytorch

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, elementwise-operations

In pytorch, I can achieve two sparse matrixes multiplication by first turning them into a dense form

```
adjdense = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(indextmp, valuetmp, torch.Size([num_nodes,num_nodes])).to_dense()
mask_dense = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(edge_index, edge_mask_list[k], torch.Size([num_nodes,num_nodes])).to_dense()
gdcdense = adjdense * mask_dense
```

but when the graph is large, this method requires a lot of memory.
Thus, How to multiply a sparse matrix by a sparse matrix element-wise in pytorch?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: does `mul` on the sparse tensors not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sim.
I have known how to do it.

adjsparse = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(indextmp, valuetmp, torch.Size([num_nodes,num_nodes]))
masksparse = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(edge_index, edge_mask_list[k],torch.Size([num_nodes,num_nodes]))

result = adjsparse.mul(masksparse)